# Ajax: invalid XML error

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I'm instructed to make an ajax call to read my xml. When I try to do so I get an parsererror.

When I run my xml through a validator, it appears to be correct.

this is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<webservices>
<flickr>
    <api>
        <key>
            ***
        </key>
        <secret>
            ***
        </secret>
    </api>
    <url>
        <api-url>
        https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search
        </api-url>
        <attr>
            tags=
        </attr>
        <attr>
            has_geo=1
        </attr>
        <attr>
            per_page=4
        </attr>
    </url>
</flickr>
</webservices>
```

ajax request:

```
var getFlickrApi = function(){

   $.ajax({
       url: 'assets/xml/config.xml',
       dataType: 'xml',
       success: handleXML,
       error: handleError
   });

};

var handleXML = function(data){
    console.log(data);
};

var handleError = function(xhr, error, message){
    console.log(error, message);
};
```

error message:

```
message: "Invalid XML: <webservices>↵    <flickr>↵        <api>↵            <key>↵                ***↵            </key>↵
```

Comment: Where is the ajax request code?

Comment: I added it right now

Comment: What happens when you set the content-type? e.g. `contentType: 'text/xml'` in the ajax request

Comment: @haxtbh Seems to give me the same error.

Comment: Also there should be a space between UTF-8 and the ? in `encoding="UTF-8"?`. It should be `encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: @haxtbh didn't fix it, added the error message in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved by simply clearing my cache. It seemed that my ajax call was accessing my previous (incorrect) xml document which was stored in cache.

Thanks for everyone who was trying to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `***` is not what is really in the xml, you must make sure that the chars in there are allowed.

For example characters like `<>&` must be encoded.

See *http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML*